# How to use Angular as a template engine

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use Angular as a template engine then I want to give the generated HTML code to another library.

I have a template file template.html:

```
<div><h1><span data-ng-show="details.rs">{{details.rs}}</span></h1></div>
```

I would like to use Angular to generate the final HTML according to what I have in my scope.

For example if details.rs=="Hi!" :

```
<div><h1><span>Hi !</span></h1></div>
```

I tried to use the $compile tool but I only get the original HTML. Here is a small sample :

```
var getTemplate = function (templateName) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        if ($templateCache.get(templateName)) {
            defer.resolve($templateCache.get(templateName));
        } else {
            $http.get(templateName, {cache: $templateCache}).then(function (data) {
                defer.resolve(data);
            });
        }
        return defer.promise;
    };

    var prepareTemplate = function (templateName) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        getTemplate(templateName).then(function (htmlTemplate) {
            defer.resolve($compile(htmlTemplate));
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };

    var buildMarkerPopup = function (properties) {
        var defer = $q.defer();
        prepareTemplate('views/template.html').then(function (template) {
            var scope = $scope.$new();
            scope.details = properties;
            $timeout(function () {
                var htmlElement = template(scope);
                $log.debug(htmlElement);
                defer.resolve(htmlElement);
            });
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

Does anyone know what I missed ?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `$interpolate` for that

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9977/

```
var exp = $interpolate('<div><h1><span data-ng-show="details.rs">{{details.rs}}</span></h1></div>');
var context = {
    details: {
        rs: 'Hi!'
    }
};

var result = exp(context);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am almost there. 
{details.rs}} is replaced !
But when details.rs is empty, the span is not removed from the dom.

Comment: Try ng-if, ng-show just do `disply:none`. I'm not sure it will work (cant test it now)

Comment: ng-if has the same behaviour. :(
It generates :
[code]<div><h1><span data-ng-if="details.rs"></span></h1>[/code]

Comment: Why don't you use any of JS template engine? http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: I only need to do that one time for a little portion of code :/

Comment: but in this example you don't need `ng-if` at all. `'<div><h1>{{details.rs}}</h1></div>'`. Or this is just an example?

Comment: This is just an example. I have paragraphes in the same div that I need to hide if they are empty (because it takes space otherwise)

Comment: If this content is already in the view, you can select it with jQuery, for example `$('.some-class').html()`

Comment: I was missing the values using Jquery.

Instead, I used the interpolate function and the following template (I use bootstrap CSS):
    `<div><h1><span class="{{details.rs?'':'hidden'}}"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> {{details.rs}}</span></h1>
</div>`

This solution is a bit uggly but it works.
Thanks for the interpolate trick :)